# any way to make the map scrollable/moveable = false?

Tags: osmdroid

I'm looking for a way to set my map scrollable/moveable to false.

I can use

```
map.setMaxZoomLevel(15);
map.setMinZoomLevel(15);
```

to set the zoomlevel to 15. But I found no way to set the map not scrollable/moveable

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to put a transparent view on top of the map view. Then you can toggle it on and off to pass through touch events or not.

Comment: but then I cant click any POI on the map :-/

Comment: just send the single taps through but not the scrolls